# CUDA peer access and peer memcpy

Tags: cuda

Do I need to enable 1-way OR 2-way peer access when using `cudaMemcpyPeer`/`cudaMemcpyPeerAsync` avoiding going through host?

I.e., are both `cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess` below required, or just one (and which one)?

```
cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(1, 0);

cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(0, 0);

size_t nbytes = ...;
// Assume these are allocated respectively.
void* src0; // Memory on device 0
void* dst1; // Memory on device 1

// Three possible cases which device is active
// during cudaMemcpyPeerAsync call (if it matters):
//    cudaSetDevice(0); // Source is active
//    cudaSetDevice(1); // Destination is active
cudaSetDevice(2); // 3rd device is active

cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(dst1, 1, src0, 0, nbytes);
```

Comment: You could simply profile the three cases using nsys to see in which cases D2D memcpy is performed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DGX or HGX system is useful to quickly gain insight.  If the traffic flows over PCIE it will be noticeably slower than if it flows over NVLink.  For proper peer enablement, the traffic will flow over NVLink.  For no or improper peer enablement, the traffic will flow over PCIE.

The following results suggest that either of the following sets of statements:

```
cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(1, 0);
```

or:

```
cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(0, 0);
```

are sufficient to enable the traffic to flow over NVLink, for this particular transfer:

```
cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(dst1, 1, src0, 0, nbytes);
```

Test case:

```
$ cat t19.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start=0){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

int main(){
#ifdef EP1
  cudaSetDevice(0);
  cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(1, 0);
#endif
#ifdef EP0
  cudaSetDevice(1);
  cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(0, 0);
#endif

  size_t nbytes = 32768*1024;
  char* src0; // Memory on device 0
  cudaSetDevice(0);
  cudaMalloc(&src0, nbytes);
  char* dst1; // Memory on device 1
  cudaSetDevice(1);
  cudaMalloc(&dst1, nbytes);
  cudaSetDevice(0);
  unsigned long long dt = dtime_usec(0);
  cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(dst1, 1, src0, 0, nbytes);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt = dtime_usec(dt);
  std::cout << dt << "us" << std::endl;

}
$ nvcc -o t19 t19.cu
$ ./t19
922us
$ nvcc -o t19 t19.cu -DEP1
$ ./t19
294us
$ nvcc -o t19 t19.cu -DEP0
$ ./t19
285us
$ nvcc -o t19 t19.cu -DEP0 -DEP1
$ ./t19
286us
$
```

CUDA 12.0